Wrapping 2D mesh on top of another 3D mesh (BabylonJS/ThreeJS)
Is there a way to wrap (not just position and rotate) a 2D mesh (mesh with no depth - monogram) on top of some 3D mesh in BabylonJS or ThreeJS in a way that would distort the 2D mesh that would fit the shape of 3D object?
Background: we use BabylonJS and we load two GLTF files – body and monogram. Body mesh is UVs mapped. Our first approach was to pick a spot from screen via mouse and use PickerInfo to get 3D coordinate from body mesh and UV coordinate from texture. We planned to then modify the UV coordinate according to 2D mesh coordinates and from that get the real 3D coordinates back. At the moment we are focusing on thin 2D mesh.
BabylonJS has function that can convert 3D picked coordinate to UV texture coordinate (getTextureCoordinates). Unfortunately as of now we have not yet found a way to pick a coordinate from texture (or mesh itself) and get back the real 3D coordinate.
transparent 3D body with 2D monogram mesh inside it that we would like to wrap on 3D body
So questions are:

Is there a way to get a 3D coordinate from 2D UV mesh or texture coordinate? If it is, this solves our problem
Is there any library that can do the warping? If not in BabylonJS, we are also exploring ThreeJS (or any other WebGL based ones)
If there is none, is there a paper that would describe how we could attempt to develop it ourselves?

Any help would be gratefully appreciated!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
